# Removing an iad View

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

I am trying to implement iad within my iOS game. I simply want to diplay the iAd during the menu of the game, but not anywhere else. I have tried several methods for removing the banner, but none have worked for me. I have an AdBannerView property within my view called advertisement, and I am able to successfully create an iad when the user opens the menu, however, when they close the menu, the iAd is still displayed. Here are the things I have tried:

```
-(void)menuDidClose{
[self.advertisement setAlpha:0];
self.advertisement.hidden = YES;
self.advertisement = nil;
[self.advertisement cancelBannerViewAction];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.advertisement];
[self.advertisement removeFromSuperview];
}
```

None of that has worked for me so far. Any other suggestions? I can get the iad to display, but not to disappear when I close the menu.

Comment: remove from superview?

Comment: Are you sure that the `self.advertisement` pointer isn't set to nil?

Comment: how do I know if the pointer is set to nil?

Comment: im using Auto Reference Count

Comment: @RDSpinz did you ever solve this? What was your solution?

Comment: I actually never figured it out. The answer below didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Setting bannerview object to 'nil' will delete this object (ARC) and banner-ads will stop displaying.

```
[self.advertisement removeFromSuperview];
self.advertisement = nil;
```

Comment: This just makes the ad refresh. The adview flashes white then loads another ad. I want to completely get rid of the ad and its frame so that there is no sign of it on the screen